# How does one implement Snow Leopard dock-style menus?

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-snow-leopard

Mac OS X Snow Leopard includes a new a new style for menus when one right-clicks the dock.

How can these be implemented elsewhere, in my own program?

Is it an API? An SPI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, for now they're private - meaning we can't use them in our own apps :-(.

If you really want them, I think you're going to have to create your own from scratch - which is no mean feat, since the current menu implementation, even in Snow Leopard, is Carbon.

Comment: I know that they are likely private, but I would like to know if anyone reverse engineered the SPI for them.